# How to implement a conditional configuration block in terraform

Tags: terraform

Is there a way to have an if statement in the middle of a configuration block?

when I have this:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "myCosmos" {
  <other stuff>

  capabilities {
    name = "EnableServerless"
  }
}
```

This is what I wanted to achieve:

```
resource "azurerm_cosmosdb_account" "myCosmos" {
  <other stuff>

  if (var.enableServerless)
  {
    capabilities {
      name = "EnableServerless"
    }
  }
}
```

I am happy to take advice if this is not the way to achieve what I intented.

Comment: You need a dynamic block: https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/expressions/dynamic-blocks